# AJAX POST issue - [[NoSuchElementException: None.get]]

Tags: scala, playframework

I can't seem to get the POST parameters to come through from an AJAX javascript POST. The error is:

```
@6angl7689 - Internal server error, for request [POST /myRoute] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NoSuchElementException: None.get]]
```

Route:

```
POST    /myRoute  controllers.Application.testPost
```

Controller code:

```
def myForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "valOne" -> text,
      "valTwo" -> text))

def testPost() = Action { implicit request =>

    val (valOne, valTwo) = myForm.bindFromRequest.get // Errors here

    println("valOne: " + valOne)
    println("valTwo: " + valTwo)

    Ok
}
```

CoffeeScript client-side:

```
params = 
   valOne: 'valOne'
   valTwo: 'valTwo'

$.ajax
   type: 'POST'
   url: '/myRoute'
   data: params
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your client code,

```
$.ajax(
   type: 'POST'
   url: '/myRoute'
   data: {valOne: 'valOne', valTwo: 'valTwo'}
);
```

This should work